# Script has no attribute 'append' after including for-loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am building a function for webscraping that extracts some elements from the `footballdatabase.eu` , and I was trying to get it to work for multiple links. The code works absolutely fine and as expected for a single link without a for-loop for requests, however when I include a for-loop to gather requests from multiple webpages I get the following error:

> in gets(href).
> 13         for j in products:
> 14             store.append(j.text).
> ---> 15             data['data'].append(store[-13:])
> 16             data = {k: v[0] for k, v in data.items()}
> 17             player_data = {'goals':[],'own goals':    [],'assists':[], 'efficiency':[],'minutes played':[],'yellow     cards':[],'red cards':[],'match starts':[],'presence':[],'shirt     number':[], 'victories':[],'draws':[],'losses':[]}

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

The aim of the function is to extract specific elements and assign these into columns and create a pandas dataframe from it, then iterate this across multiple links that stack into a single dataframe.

Can someone please shed some light on how to fix this?

```
href = ['https://www.footballdatabase.eu/en/player/details/10973-lionel-messi',
'https://www.footballdatabase.eu/en/player/details/43411-robert-lewandowski']

store = []


def getsit(href):
    data = {'data':[]}
    for k in range(0, len(list_of_players),1):
        r = requests.get(href[k])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        products = soup.find('div', {'id':'block_2_5'}).find_all('a')
        for j in products:
            store.append(j.text)
        data['data'].append(store[-13:]) #get only the last 13 rows
        data = {k: v[0] for k, v in data.items()} #flatten the lists
        player_data = {'goals':[],'own goals':[],'assists':[], 'efficiency':[],'minutes played':[],'yellow cards':[],'red cards':[],'match starts':[],'presence':[],'shirt number':[], 'victories':[],'draws':[],'losses':[]}
        for i in zip(itertools.cycle([1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]), data['data']):
            if i[0] == 1:
                player_data['goals'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 2:
                player_data['own goals'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 3:
                player_data['assists'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 4:
                player_data['efficiency'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 5:
                player_data['minutes played'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 6:
                player_data['yellow cards'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 7:
                player_data['red cards'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 8:
                player_data['match starts'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 9:
                player_data['presence'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 10:
                player_data['shirt number'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 11:
                player_data['victories'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 12:
                player_data['draws'].append(i[1])
            elif i[0] == 13:
                player_data['losses'].append(i[1])
    all_data = pd.DataFrame(player_data)
    return(all_data)
```

Comment: Your code can be greatly simplified by using a list of names and accessing it: `player_data[names[i[0]]].append(i[1])`

Comment: Please attach the entire error trace. In particular, at which line does the error occur?

Comment: @Elazar I cannot seem to get you suggestion to work

Answer (score 0):

You re-assign `data` inside the loop. I think you want a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here, your problem is coming from the line `data = {k: v[0] for k, v in data.items()}`. The issue is that `data` is being reassigned for every iteration of the loop. This wasn't an issue before adding the loop since the only `data.append()` calls happen *before* it gets reassigned. The value you're reassigning to `data` is `v[0]` which is a string element of the list and not the list itself.

Without real knowledge of what you're trying to accomplish in the big picture, it's a little hard to say exactly how to fix this so your code works as intended. That being said, I'm not seeing a real use for `data = {k: v[0] for k, v in data.items()}`, so removing that line would fix the problem. If that first element data is should be stored in a separate variable.

Comment: The error says it is coming from the line before it. The line you are referring to tries to flatten the double lists within the dictionary into a single list

Comment: I know it says the error is coming from the line before it, but that's not what the issue is. pulling out `k,v in data.items()` returns a key/value. Here `v` is a list of strings. Thus  `data[k] = v[0]` assigns values for each key in data to type string. So on the second iteration you're trying to do `str.append()`